# Play music across multiple devices at once

Tags: itunes, icloud, network, wifi, appletv

I'm pretty well invested into the Apple ecosystem. I'm home sharing music between two Apple TVs & my MBP. Is it possible to play the same song through all the Apple TVs in sync? I'm basically trying to make the most expensive redneck housewide sound system.

Edit: I am aware I can setup a playlist and hit play on all of the individual devices. I'm looking for a central control platform.

Bonus: if it is possible, can I get the iPads and iPhones in on the shenanigans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a computer with iTunes, [you can AirPlay your music](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19497?locale=en_US) to multiple AirPort Expresses and Apple TVs simultaneously and selectively.

[image: itunes multiple airplay]

This is not the case when streaming from iPhones and iPads; you can only choose one AirPlay output from them.

I must say that this looks a little bit like a dead end, since Apple [reportedly ended their networking hardware division](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/nov/22/apple-stops-making-wireless-airport-routers-shuts-division) (hence no more AirPort Express) and [removed the audio output from the latest Apple TV](http://www.macworld.com/article/2983252/hardware/apple-tv-drops-optical-audio-out-how-to-pump-up-the-volume-again.html).

Answer (score 3):

The [Airfoil apps from Rogue Amoeba](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) will almost certainly do everything you want, including sending the audio to iOS devices, AppleTVs, Macs and even Bluetooth speakers and Google Chromecast devices, all at the same time and in sync. Airfoil Satellite lets Macs, Windows, and iOS devices act as speakers for the Airfoil and Airplay sources.

Answer (score 1):

This app called [Porthole](https://www.dangercove.com/porthole/) seems to say it does what you want. Worth a try?

[image]

Comment: I see porthole is dead... with a note about "with macOS Mojave and iOS 12 Porthole has been made fully obsolete by the built-in features of Apple’s desktop and mobile operating system." .... yet it doesn't even explain how in the world that works lol.